# Why is fragment calling OnCreate / OnCreateView when using fragment transactions with FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin.android

The main page of my application has a FrameLayout.

I'm instantiating two fragments when the activity starts, and I'm trying to use a menu button to swap between the fragment.

```
scanHistoryFrag = new HistoryFragment();
scanFrag = new ScanFragment();
```

I never replace these objects - I use the same ones throughout the lifecycle of the application. However, when I swap them in my FrameLayout...

```
private void ChangeFragment(Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment fragment)
{
    Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction ft = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
    ft.Replace(Resource.Id.fragmentContainer, fragment);
    ft.Commit();
}
```

OnCreate and OnCreateView are called on the Fragment again... which means any adjustments I made post creation on that fragment are overwritten with initial values again. I can't seem to find any explanation for why this is happening or how I might avoid it.

The ChangeFragment method is being called by OnOptionsItemSelected, as I'm using a menu button to toggle them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I never replace these objects - I use the same ones throughout the lifecycle of the application.

Initialization of a subclass of `Fragment` just create a instance of this class object, the constructor of this class will be called, but it will not go through the lifecycle of `Fragment` unless this `Fragment` is added, for more information, you can refer to [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html). To understand it easier, I personal think the instance saves the data state of this `Fragment` class, but the events of lifecycle handle the view state of this `Fragment`.

> which means any adjustments I made post creation on that fragment are overwritten with initial values again.

Yes, you're right. To avoid overwritting with initial values again, we can cache the fragment's view in `OnCreateView` for example like this:

```
private View rootView;

public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
    // return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.YourFragment, container, false);

    if (rootView == null)
    {
        //first time creating this fragment view
        rootView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragmentlayout1, container, false);

        //Initialization
        //TODO:
    }
    else
    {
        //not first time creating this fragment view
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup)rootView.Parent;
        if (parent != null)
        {
            parent.RemoveView(rootView);
        }
    }
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is happening in the else block? The code works as expected but I don't understand why a view is being removed

Comment: @aufty, here in `OnCreateView`, we actually add view into `ViewGroup` to show this view, but `rootView` in "else" block is only the cache of the view, before adding this cache to the `ViewGroup`, we need to judge whether this cache been already added into `ViewGroup`. If it is added, we remove it, otherwise the error like "this rootView already has a parent" will occur.